# Get parent tag while searching for string or number in XML using a shellscript

Tags: xml, linux, bash, shell, parsing

I have a file with an structure similar to this one:

```
<log id="1" date="11/11/1999">
  <data>
    <param id="1" value="30">
    <param id="2" value="John">
    <param id="3" value="Success">
  </data>
</log>
<log id="2" date="11/12/1999">
  <data>
    <param id="1" value="20">
    <param id="2" value="Albert">
    <param id="3" value="Failure">
  </data>
</log>
```

I've been trying to use `grep` or `xmllint` to show **only** the log tag where an specific value is provided (i.e. 30). My idea is that, by searching the number 30 or John it retrieves the entire log entry where those values exist. So if I searched for 30 it would return:

```
<log id="1" date="11/11/1999">
  <data>
    <param id="1" value="30">
    <param id="2" value="John">
    <param id="3" value="Success">
  </data>
</log>
```

What's the best way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your XML is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `xpath` to query for specific nodes

```
xpath -e '//param[@value="30"]/../..'
```

this returns the parent's parent of a node with a param with value 30

Answer (score 0):

Using an HTML parser with your broken input file (with [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath)):

### File :

```
<root>
<log id="1" date="11/11/1999">
  <data>
    <param id="1" value="30">
    <param id="2" value="John">
    <param id="3" value="Success">
  </data>
</log>
<log id="2" date="11/12/1999">
  <data>
    <param id="1" value="20">
    <param id="2" value="Albert">
    <param id="3" value="Failure">
  </data>
</log>
</root>
```

### Command :

```
$ saxon-lint --html --xpath '//param[@value="30"]/ancestor::log' file.html
```

### Output :

```
<log xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="1" date="11/11/1999">
<data>
<param valuetype="data" id="1" value="30"/>
<param valuetype="data" id="2" value="John"/>
<param valuetype="data" id="3" value="Success"/>
</data>
</log>
```

Check https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint (my own project)